# Is conditionally rendering a React component instead of raw markup save performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, ecmascript-6

This is something that makes sense in my head but I haven't been able to find any facts/articles to back this up.

Essentially is doing something like

```
render() {
  return (
    someBoolean && <div>Some Markup</div>
  )
}
```

less performant than

```
render() {
  return (
    someBoolean && <SomeComponent />
  )
}
```

where `SomeComponent` has the same exact markup as the previous example.

My reasoning is since the markup will have to be created on every re-render it'll take up more memory whereas the saved component `SomeComponent` will be referenced in memory and won't have to be created on every re-render.

Is there somewhere in the react docs that explains this more thoroughly?
Or is this reasoning not accurate?

Comment: While I'm not sure how much of a difference it would make, I feel like you shouldn't worry about it unless you've profiled and pinned this as a performance pitfall. This falls under micro-opt territory

Comment: Clarification question: Is it defined as something like `const SomeComponent = <div>Some Markup</div>`? The second example in the question makes it seem like it's a higher-order component, which _would still_ create a new instance on every render.

Comment: Yea I meant by `SomeComponent` being a higher order component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSX is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`. As it can be seen in [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbADvAdgUzQF2gbwCgAnLAEwyIAoBKfA6aE7AVyLWkvoegiQwCF48EBjDsAZOOgAeUgEsAbgD4Ayn2gBZMEQDWzZNID085V2oEAvgWJkKNOgyat2nbjz6DhoiVOlrEGAgo6Fi4hkpmlpZAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=), they are

```
return someBoolean && React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  "Some Markup"
);
```

and

```
return someBoolean && React.createElement(SomeComponent, null);
```

respectively.

When `someBoolean` is falsy, `React.createElement` isn't called and `render` becomes no-op.

`SomeComponent` isn't cached, it is re-created every time. In comparison with raw markup, it provides negligible overhead, considering that it is a stateless component:

```
const SomeComponent = () => <div>Some Markup</div>;
```

Both options are very fast and aren't supposed to be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's conditional or not is not an issue, as neither will be evaluated past the `&&` if `someBoolean` is false.

The real question is whether a defined React subcomponent has a performance advantage or penalty versus plain JSX markup defined within another component. For practical purposes, there is no performance difference unless you are making use of custom functions for lifecycle hooks.

For example, if you use a subcomponent, you may define a separate `shouldComponentUpdate` method within that component and thereby decouple its updates from the parent.  In the case of plain JSX, it will update as part of the parent component.